# Getting weird buffer around my 'Notes' button here, and it's the only one that opens a hidden <div>, could that be responsible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

If you click on "Create Task" button in the top right, you can see it.

https://acchang.github.io/ProjectToDoList/

I have a slight idea why, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The notes button opens up a field. When I click it, the gap closes up.

I have my code structured such that all the elements go in a `taskInputContainer`. `taskInputContainer` goes in a `taskOverallContainer`.

`taskNotesInput` is also in `taskOverallContainer` and appears when clicked.

I can make `taskNotesInput` show up underneath `taskInputContainer` by using `flex-direction: column;` in `taskOverallContainer` but the gaps around the notes button remain.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the applicable portion of my css:

```css
/* task list */
#TaskList{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.taskHolder {
  background-color: rgb(202, 200, 198);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

/* Create task */

.taskOverallContainer {
  display: none;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.taskInputContainer {
display: flex;
align-items: baseline;
padding: 5px;
width: 100%;
}

.taskEditProject {
  display: none;
  }

#taskPrioritySection {
  display: inline;
  flex-direction: column;
  order: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 10%;
}

    .taskPrioritySelector {
      display: none;
      }

#taskInputFieldHolder {
  order: 2;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 35%;
}

    #taskInputField {
      border: 0px;
      /* border-bottom: single; */
      }

#taskCalendarField {
  order: 3;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 25%;
}

    #taskCalendarSelector {
      border: 0px;
    }

#taskNotesField {
  order: 4;
  /* display: flex; // causes padding */
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 8%;
}

    .taskNotesInput {
      display: none;
    }

    #taskNotesInput {
      margin-left: 150px;
    }

    .taskEditNotes {
      display: none;
      }

    #taskNotesBox {
      display: flex;
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
    }

#taskProjectSection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 12%;
  order: 5;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

    .taskProjectSelector {
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
    }

#addTaskField {
  display: inline;
  order: 6;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 10%;
  }

.flex {
display: flex;
}
```

And the relevant code, if it helps:
https://github.com/acchang/ProjectToDoList/blob/main/src/createTaskInput.js

Thank you!

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: ok, I will take a new crack at phrasing this question in a bit, have some things to attend to...